# Laravel HasManyThrough with relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I have 3 models (category , topic , post) which are related to each other with HasManyThrough eloquent relation:

Category Model has many Topic's' and Topic Model has many Posts 
my Post model also another 'hasOne' related model named 'FeaturedImage' that return posts image.

now i need to fetch all posts of one category with their image but it seems impossible with Laravel Eloquent.
Laravel dosen't support something like this :

```
        $posts = $category->posts->with('featuredImage')->paginate(...);
```

is there any solution to solve this problem with Laravel's Eloquent Or Query builder?

Comment: is this works `$category->posts` ? I mean to say, is there any relationship between category and posts ? are they directly connected ?

Comment: yes.. there is the eloquent's hasManyTrouth relation between category and posts

Comment: are you applying pagination on category ?

Comment: I've solved this problem with a direct hasMany relation between Category model and Post Model . Thanks for your help Bro